# Using OR in form filters

Tags: ms-access, vba

My goal is to get records where person name matches the filter, and either sale month is matching or paid month is matching.

My filter is giving me results for all people and not filtering by Person Name.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Filter3) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([PERSONNAME] Like ""*" & Me.Filter3 & "*"") AND "
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.Filter4) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([SaleMonth] Like ""*" & Me.Filter4 & "*"") OR "
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.Filter5) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([PAIDMONTH] Like ""*" & Me.Filter5 & "*"") AND "
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need a pair of parens around the two OR criteria (all those original parens are not necessary). Which means you will need some more conditional code if you want to allow only one of the OR criteria to be provided. Since you are using LIKE with wildcard, why bother with conditionals at all? I prefer apostrophe delimiter.

```
strWhere = "[PERSONNAME] Like '*" & Me.Filter3 & "*' AND ([SaleMonth] Like '*" & Me.Filter4 & "*' OR [PAIDMONTH] Like '*" & Me.Filter5 & "*')"
```

On second thought, that probably won't work with OR. If the criteria used only AND then it would. Try:

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Filter3) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "[PERSONNAME] Like '*" & Me.Filter3 & "*' AND "
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.Filter4) And Not IsNull(Me.Filter5) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([SaleMonth] Like '*" & Me.Filter4 & "*' OR [PAIDMONTH] Like '*" & Me.Filter5 & "*') AND "
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.Filter4) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "[SaleMonth] Like '*" & Me.Filter4 & "*' AND "
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.Filter5) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "[PAIDMONTH] Like '*" & Me.Filter5 & "*' AND "
End If
```

Comment: but they are each under individual if statements, so how do I do this keeping the if statements

Comment: @June7 If `Me.Filter4` is null, `SaleMonth` will match everything regardless of the value of `Me.Filter5`.

Comment: Yeah, edited my answer already, and then I see you went similar route as well. Do wonder if OP really wants or needs pattern matching and really should use = instead. I suspect the code continues to truncate the extra `AND `.

Answer (score 0):

As messy as it looks, I think you'll probably need to do something like the following to ensure that the parentheses are correct in all cases and to account for all possible combinations of `Null` and `Not Null` for the three variables whilst maintaining correct SQL:

```vb
If Not IsNull(Me.Filter3) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([PERSONNAME] Like '*" & Me.Filter3 & "*') "
    If (Not IsNull(Me.Filter4)) Or (Not IsNull(Me.Filter5)) Then 
        strWhere = strWhere & "AND "
    End If
End If
If (Not IsNull(Me.Filter4)) And (Not IsNull(Me.Filter5)) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "(([SaleMonth] Like '*" & Me.Filter4 & "*') OR ([PAIDMONTH] Like '*" & Me.Filter5 & "*')) "
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.Filter4) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([SaleMonth] Like '*" & Me.Filter4 & "*') "
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.Filter5) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([PAIDMONTH] Like '*" & Me.Filter5 & "*') "
End If
```

Though, be aware that construction of SQL code in this manner is of course open to SQL injection.

Comment: it is giving ERROR 3450 - syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause. May be just a small missing syntax.

Comment: @June7 looks like it is working. I am going to validate the results more because I have lot of records, but does look like it is working thank you.

Comment: I do have the following as part of the code too, to truncate the extra And

Comment: lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
    If lngLen > 0 Then     'Nah: there was nothing in the string.
        'MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
    'Else                    'Yep: there is something there, so remove the " AND " at the end.
        strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
        'For debugging, remove the leading quote on the next line. Prints to Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).
        'Debug.Print strWhere
        
        'Finally, apply the string as the form's Filter.
        Me.Filter = strWhere
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If